# How to make all the pages authenticated with the login page

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have five `.aspx` pages in my project, first one is the login page and other are home, index, etc. The problem is that when user enter the user ID and password in the login page, it will direct to next page that is home page. But when I simply put the URL of the home page it also display the page without any login authentication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of OP's [later question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382800/how-to-make-login-page-in-asp-net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the current structure of your project, you can create a `Session` variable on the login page after verifying the user credentials and store logged in user details i.e.

in your login page, login button click handler do this:

```
  protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
      string username= txtUsername.Text;
      string pwd = txtPassword.Text;

      //call your logic to verify user credentials.
      VerifyUserCredentialFromDb(username, pwd);

     if(UserValid)
     {
        Session["User"] = GetUserObject(username,pwd);

        //whatever your logic is, make sure, you create the Session object, before 
        //below line,whereever you are doing it
        Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
     }
 }
```

and in the Page_load of all the other pages

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if(Session["User"]==null)
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
  }
```

Btw, You should look into [Forms Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET).

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) simple forms auth implementation

Comment: if ((Login.UserName == "ADMIN") && (Login.Password == "ADMIN") || (Login.UserName == "admin") && (Login.Password == "admin"))
        {
            Session["username"] = Login.UserName;
            Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
        }                                                                    code for login page and i m using the same code given by u in every pages inside the page_Lode ...bt nt working..

Comment: it has to work. you are creating Session["username"] on the login page. make sure u are using same on the others as well and not Session["User"]

Answer (score 1):

You can control authentication in the web.config file using Forms Authentication...

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="MySite" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<location path="Members">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This will block all unauthorized access to the Members folder in the website. So, if you were to just type in `http://localhost/Members/Default.aspx` into your address bar, it'll send you back to the login page at `localhost/Login.aspx`.

While this specifically denies access to the pages in the Members folder, you could rewrite it to block access to all but the home page by replacing `<allow users="?" />` with the `<deny users="?" />` you see below it.

Typically you'd also want to write a check in those pages that looks something like this (C#):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
    {
        // User is logged in, continue
    }
    else
    {
        // No valid login...
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save user credentials on session.. and in page load event on aspx pages

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   
  if(Session["Username"]==null)
  Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
 }
```

if there is no session,it redirects to login page..