# How to make login page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm working in a project in which I have an employee registration page where employees can register themselves and select their user ID and password, which are saved in a SQL database. I want to use that user ID and password to log in.

Comment: Can you please review your question and clarify it?

Comment: ASP.Net has this built in - A simple Google search will get you going: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178329(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @JamieKeeling, that's assuming the OP is leveraging the membership database, and I don't think that's the case. For that reason, I provided an answer for a custom login solution.

Comment: I've downvoted, as there's no evidence of prior effort, research, detail or code. OP, please be willing to do a thorough web-search prior to asking questions - learning self-sufficiency will make you a better programmer `:)`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Good point, +1 to you Sir.

Comment: Possible duplicate of OP's [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332471/how-to-make-all-the-pages-authenticated-with-the-login-page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, before I begin let's talk about the assumptions I'm going to have to make because you provided almost no information in your question. Bear in mind I have to make these assumptions so I can provide some kind of answer.

### Database Schema

I'm going to assume the database schema looks something like this:

```
... TABLE users (
    userid INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    username VARCHAR(50),
    password VARCHAR(50)
)
```

### Web Form

I'm going to assume the web form might look something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="login" Text="Login" runat="server" />
```

Alright, so now that I've made some assumptions, here is how you would do it with the assumptions I've made. First we would hookup the `Click` event:

```
<asp:Button ID="login" Text="Login" runat="server" OnClick="LoginUser" />
```

and then we need the event handler in the code behind:

```
public void LoginUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    cn.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password", cn);

    using (cn)
    {
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", this.username.Text);
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", this.password.Text);

        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            // do something here, like show a label stating that the username
            // and password combination didn't match

            return;
        }

        // if you get here then it was a valid login
    }
}
```

### Security

I made one more assumption in my example, for the sake of simplicity and brevity, I didn't have an encrypted password in the database. You should. But you can add to this example as you get that into place, if you don't already.

Comment: +1, great answer. I'm not a .net programmer, but wonder if there's a module to handle this problem in a best-practice way? A templatable login form plus a hashed and salted storage format?

Comment: @halfer, thanks! And as far as something that's built-in. It's not wholly built-in, meaning you're still going to have to do some work, but you'll want to look at ASP.NET Membership (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx). It has a predefined schema by Microsoft for users and group membership. It also has some built-in attributing. And it's more leveraged in MVC than ever before. It's where Microsoft is going - but there are a number of times a simple users table along with a simple MD5 hash is sufficient and much easier.